# The Order Of $U_8$

Tags: group-theory

I need to write cayley table for $U_8$ to start I wanted to know how many elements are there in $U_8$ so I used the formula $|U_n|=n\cdot (1-\frac{1}{p_1})\cdots(1-\frac{1}{p_k})$ where $n=p_1\cdot p_2\cdots p_k$ so in this case we have $8=2^3$ so $|U_8|=8\cdot (1-\frac{1}{2})^3=1$ which is obviously wrong.

Let say I would find the answer which is $4$ how we need find all $a$ s.t $gcd(a,8)=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is right, but you didn't apply it in the right manner. $p_i$'s are **distinct** prime divisors of $n$. So by the formula we have that:

$$|U_n| = n\left(1 - \frac 12 \right) = 4$$

Now to find the invertible elements as you have said we need to find all $a$ s.t. $\gcd(a,8)=1$. Now use the fact that the elements in $U_4$ are always less than $8$. In fact we are working modulo $8$, so this should take care of it. Now as we have $8$ choices it's not hard to find the wanted $4$ integers. Moreover you can see that $\gcd(a,8) \not = 1 \iff 2 \mid a$. So the wanted answer is all odd positive integers less than $8$.